# How to change activeTintColor in TabBar (react-navigation) dynamically ?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation` in my app, I want to know how is possible to change `activeTintColor` in TabBar dynamically?

I have such code, but it doesn't change activeTintColor:

```
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    actionButton: {
      title: _('create'),
      icon: 'plus',
      onPress: () => navigation.navigate('EventCreate')
    },
    tabBarLabel: _('calendar'),
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => <Icon featherName="calendar" active={focused}/>,
    tabBarOptions: { activeTintColor:'red'}
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by marking a *Custom Tab Bar Component*.

```
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const TabBar = TabNavigator.Presets.Default.tabBarComponent

const CustomTabBar = ({...props}) => {
    props.activeTintColor = //... change the color based on screen navigation state 
    return <TabBar {...props} />
}
```

and use it as

```
const CustomTabs = TabNavigator(
    {
        // ...Screens
    },
    {
        tabBarComponent: CustomTabBar,
    },
);
```

The *Custom Tab Bar Component* has access to these [**props**](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/1a0ebfeb904c64dcc377ad032d46b4dd20fd5362/src/views/TabView/TabBarBottom.js#L206).

The **navigation state** objects are defined as in [**here**](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators.html#navigation-state)